# ionic 1.x : crop image

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, crop

I have two buttons, the first one for browse image from gallery and the second one  for taking photo. I'm using `cordova camera plugin` for two cases.

After choosing an image, I want to crop it before to send to server using `cordova file transfer plugin`. I've tried to use several plugins such as `jr-crop`, `angular-image-crop`, `ngImgCrop`. The problem is that plugins returns a base64 image, but I want to get the image url (not dataUrl). Any help please !

Comment: did you find a Solution for this !

Comment: I made my own solution, adapted to my situation. The code is in the answer because is too long to put it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution (@egycode) :

```
$scope.image_gallery = function() {
    var options = {
        quality: 100,
        correctOrientation: true,
        sourceType: 0
    };
    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.crop(data);
        console.log('camera data image_gallery: ' + angular.toJson(data));
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('camera error image_gallery: ' + angular.toJson(error));
    });
}

$scope.crop = function(url) {
    $jrCrop.crop({
        url: url,
        width: 261,
        height: 362
    }).then(function(canvas) {
        console.log(canvas);
        var image = canvas.toDataURL();
        //var image is the result, you can show it using : $scope.pictureUrl = image;
    }, function() {
        // User canceled or couldn't load image.
    });
}
```